# Windows 7 - GPO list

Tags: windows-7, windows

Does anyone have a comrehensive list of objects to manage Windows 7 environments - 2003 and 2008 R2 domains?

Answer (score 1):

You can find `Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server` [from Microsoft's site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb&displaylang=en) (downloadable Excel files)